# How do I solve a "too complex expression" in an Access query

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

In Excel VBA I am looping through the tables of databases `Data.mdb` in the folders `N` and `O`
The databases contain the same tables but the data may differ.

While looping through the tables I am returning the differences between the two tables. This works without error, except for some tables with a lot of fields.

In those cases an error is thrown: `Expression too complex`

Here is an example of a "too complex" query

```
SELECT x.* FROM 

(SELECT * FROM tblA IN 'C:\Users\A\Desktop\N\Data.mdb') x LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM tblA IN 'C:\Users\A\Desktop\O\Data.mdb') y ON 

(x.A = y.A) 

WHERE (

( x.A & ';' & x.B & ';' & x.C & ';' & x.D & ';' & x.E & ';' & x.F & ';' & x.G & ';' & x.H & ';' & x.I & ';' & x.J & ';' & x.K & ';' & x.L & ';' & x.M & ';' & x.N & ';' & x.O & ';' & x.P & ';' & x.Q & ';' & x.R & ';' & x.S & ';' & x.T & ';' & x.U & ';' & x.V & ';' & x.W & ';' & x.X & ';' & x.Y & ';' & x.Z & ';' & x.AA & ';' & x.AB & ';' & x.AC & ';' & x.AD & ';' & x.AE & ';' & x.AF & ';' & x.AG & ';' & x.AH & ';' & x.AI & ';' & x.AJ & ';' & x.AK & ';' & x.AL & ';' & x.AM & ';' & x.AN & ';' & x.AO & ';' & x.AP & ';' & x.AQ & ';' & x.AR & ';' & x.AS & ';' & x.AT & ';' & x.AU & ';' & x.AV & ';' & x.AW & ';' & x.AX ';' & x.AY & ';' & x.AZ & ';' & x.BA & ';' & x.BB & ';' & x.BC & ';' & x.BD & ';' & x.BE & ';' & x.BF & ';' & x.BG & ';' & x.BH & ';' & x.BI) <> 

( y.A & ';' & y.B & ';' & y.C & ';' & y.D & ';' & y.E & ';' & y.F & ';' & y.G & ';' & y.H & ';' & y.I & ';' & y.J & ';' & y.K & ';' & y.L & ';' & y.M & ';' & y.N & ';' & y.O & ';' & y.P & ';' & y.Q & ';' & y.R & ';' & y.S & ';' & y.T & ';' & y.U & ';' & y.V & ';' & y.W & ';' & y.X & ';' & y.Y & ';' & y.Z & ';' & y.AA & ';' & y.AB & ';' & y.AC & ';' & y.AD & ';' & y.AE & ';' & y.AF & ';' & y.AG & ';' & y.AH & ';' & y.AI & ';' & y.AJ & ';' & y.AK & ';' & y.AL & ';' & y.AM & ';' & y.AN & ';' & y.AO & ';' & y.AP & ';' & y.AQ & ';' & y.AR & ';' & y.AS & ';' & y.AT & ';' & y.AU & ';' & y.AV & ';' & y.AW & ';' & y.AX ';' & y.AY & ';' & y.AZ & ';' & y.BA & ';' & y.BB & ';' & y.BC & ';' & y.BD & ';' & y.BE & ';' & y.BF & ';' & y.BG & ';' & y.BH & ';' & y.BI)

)
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps you could split it into several steps.

Comment: Sounds promising, but I have no clue how to split this into several steps

Comment: Not including semi-colon in concatenation will reduce number of characters and should get the same data comparison. That will reduce number of characters although probably still not enough.

Comment: @June7 is it the number of fields or the number of characters which is resulting in the expression being too complex? If it is the number of characters than my case is even worse because the fieldnames are longer than in my given example...

Comment: @MK01111000 June7 said "That will reduce number of characters although probably still not enough"...

Comment: I just checked some Access specs and limits I was thinking of are for query designer. So unless you exceed 255 fields or 64,000 characters for SQL statement, don't see issue.

Comment: Would creating queries based on each table and including the concatenated fields help? You would then base the final query on these queries.

Comment: @June7 If the limits are 255 fields or 64000 characters, then something else seems to be off with my query. This is, that it only throws the error on tables with a lot of fields...

Comment: Without working with data, really can't offer any more. Might want to post to forum that allows attaching files and provide databases with issue. Why using Excel?